# SQL create table column AS SELECT FROM OTHER TABLE

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

My problem is I cannot create proper DDL statement 'create table' with column based on 2 columns from other table.

The final table should looks like after:

```
CREATE TABLE PRACOWNICY_ZESPOLY AS
  SELECT 12*PLACA_POD + NVL(PLACA_DOD,0) AS ROCZNA_PLACA FROM PRAC;

ALTER TABLE PRACOWNICY_ZESPOLY 
  ADD (
      NAZWISKO VARCHAR(20),
      POSADA VARCHAR(20),
      ZESPOL NUMBER(4),
      ADRES_PRACY VARCHAR(20) );
```

I was trying something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE PRACOWNICY_ZESPOLY (
  NAZWISKO VARCHAR(20),
  POSADA VARCHAR(20),
  ZESPOL NUMBER(4),
  ADRES_PRACY VARCHAR(20),
  ROCZNA_PLACA NUMBER(6,2) AS (SELECT 12*PLACA_POD + NVL(PLACA_DOD,0) FROM PRAC));
```

Result:

> SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression

```
CREATE TABLE PRACOWNICY_ZESPOLY (
  NAZWISKO VARCHAR(20),
  POSADA VARCHAR(20),
  ZESPOL NUMBER(4),
  ADRES_PRACY VARCHAR(20))
  AS SELECT 12*PLACA_POD + NVL(PLACA_DOD,0) FROM PRAC;
```

Result:

> SQL Error: ORA-01773: may not specify column datatypes in this CREATE TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE PRACOWNICY_ZESPOLY AS
  SELECT 12*PLACA_POD + NVL(PLACA_DOD,0) AS ROCZNA_PLACA FROM PRAC, 
  (NAZWISKO VARCHAR(20),
  POSADA VARCHAR(20),
  ZESPOL NUMBER(4),
  ADRES_PRACY VARCHAR(20));
```

Result:

> SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: The only time a computer is instructed to do something and it is "w/o result" is when ***you have pulled out the plug.***  In every other case, there is some kind of reaction, like an error message perhaps.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to achieve here? 

Are you simply looking for a way to combine data from two different tables? If so, create a view. 

Do you need your new "table" to somehow be updated as soon as data in the source table updates? If so, create a trigger to add the data. 

If you just want to see a column that is nothing more than an addition of two other columns, why not create a calculated column in the source table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `create` and an `insert` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE PRACOWNICY_ZESPOLY 
(
  ROCZNA_PLACA  number, 
  NAZWISKO      VARCHAR(20),
  POSADA        VARCHAR(20),
  ZESPOL        NUMBER(4),
  ADRES_PRACY   VARCHAR(20)
);

insert into PRACOWNICY_ZESPOLY (ROCZNA_PLACA) 
SELECT 12 * PLACA_POD + NVL(PLACA_DOD,0) 
FROM PRAC;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a working solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57151207/6071045) question.

You need to combine get_ddl with CTAS syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that to solve

> Error: ORA-01773: may not specify column datatypes in this CREATE TABLE

[this article](http://turfybot.free.fr/oracle/9i/errors/ORA-01773.html) work:

> How to deal with ORA-01773 from Oracle 9i ?
> Remove column datatypes. The datatypes of the SELECT list expressions are automatically used as the column datatypes.