# Oracle: is it possible to create a copy of a IOT using CTAS without specifying columns?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I make use of the CTAS (Create Table As Select) syntax to create a copy of a table, in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE2 AS SELECT * FROM TABLE1;
```

So TABLE2 is a full copy of TABLE1, with all its columns.

I would like to make the same thing with the IOT tables.

But if I try to execute the following:

```
CREATE TABLE IOT_TABLE2 ORGANIZATION INDEX AS SELECT * FROM IOT_TABLE1;
```

I obtain:

```
ORA-25175: no PRIMARY KEY constraint found
```

There is some trick to do that, or is simply impossible to create a copy without specifying all columns?

Comment: The problem is, CTAS creates a copy of the table but not its constraints (not indexes, triggers, etc). An IOT must have a primary key and it can't be inferred from the projection of the created table. Hence  ORA-25175.

Comment: Do you really like to create a copy of your table or do you try to reorganize a table?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit My environment needs to create copies of tables, not to reorganize existing tables. If you don't know the purpose please avoid criticizing working solutions. Thanks

Comment: @AlessandroC, I did not criticise anything nor down vote anything I just asked a question because your request look rather special. .

Comment: sorry @WernfriedDomscheit

Answer (score 0):

try as follows

```
CREATE TABLE IOT_TABLE2(id, col1, col2 .... , CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (id)) 
ORGANIZATION INDEX AS SELECT * FROM IOT_TABLE1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4eb1df532ad47825e3830dcaf31a1fd5)*

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name hint, I have found a proper solution.

Given this exemplification IOT DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE "IOT_TABLE1" 
   (    "COLUMN1" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "COLUMN2" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "COLUMN3" NUMBER(18,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "COLUMN4" BINARY_DOUBLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "TABLE1_IOT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("COLUMN1", "COLUMN2", "COLUMN3") ENABLE
   ) ORGANIZATION INDEX NOCOMPRESS;
```

This is the SQL statement that can make a perfect copy of an IOT:

```
DECLARE 
    stmt VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN 
    DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param(DBMS_METADATA.session_transform, 'SQLTERMINATOR', false);
    DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param(DBMS_METADATA.session_transform, 'PRETTY', true);
    DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param(DBMS_METADATA.session_transform, 'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES', false);
    DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param(DBMS_METADATA.session_transform, 'STORAGE', false);
    SELECT TO_CHAR(DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl('TABLE','IOT_TABLE1')) INTO stmt FROM DUAL;
    stmt := REPLACE(stmt, 'TABLE1_IOT_PK', 'TABLE2_IOT_PK');
    stmt := REPLACE(stmt, 'TABLE1', 'TABLE2');
    stmt := regexp_replace(stmt, '^\s+(\()*\s*"(\w+).+$',chr(9)||'\1"\2",',1,0,'m');
    stmt := stmt || 'AS SELECT * FROM TABLE1';
    dbms_output.put_line(stmt);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE STMT;
END;
```

There are 3 replacements:

1. The PK name
2. The TABLE name
3. The TYPE informations must be eliminated, otherwise it fails with ORA-01773

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cb85ef7e0f2bbc62c8df497fef63b169) db<>fiddle